# ¿Cómo insertar una gran cantidad de texto en un EditText de kotlin sin congelar la UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, edittext

**Descripción del problema:**
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de notas en Kotlin con dos fragmentos: A y B. El fragmento A envía una cadena de texto al fragmento B, la cual se muestra en un EditText. Sin embargo, al ser una cadena larga (por ejemplo, 30000 caracteres), el EditText tarda en mostrarla, causando bloqueos en la interfaz de usuario. Otras aplicaciones en Kotlin, como TalkFree, no presentan este problema y muestran la nota al instante. ¿Cómo puedo evitar este retraso y mejorar la experiencia de usuario?

**Código relevante:**

```
// Fragment A
private fun editTask(id: String, task: String) {
    findNavController().navigate(
        TasksListFragmentDirections.actionTasksListFragmentToEditTaskFragment(taskToEdit = id, task = task, fontSize = tasksListViewModel.preferences.value.textSize)
    )
}

// Fragment B, recive la nota en otra parte, pero aca la inserto en el EditText
private fun insertTextIntoEditText(
    text: String,
    editText: EditText,
    fontSize: Float? = null
) {
    if (fontSize != null) {
        editText.textSize = fontSize
    }
    editText.setSelection(0)
    editText.setText(text)
}
```

**XML del EditText del Fragment B:**

```
<ScrollView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/containerTopAppBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:hint="@string/editTaskHint_ES"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="125dp"
            android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody1"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</ScrollView>
```

**Intentos de solución:**
He probado utilizar un RecyclerView de EditTexts, pero esto limita la selección del texto. También intenté utilizar TextWatcher, pero surgen problemas con el desplazamiento y la selección del texto.

**He utilizado la libreria BigEditText:** Al funcionar con un recyclerview de EditTexts, el problema principal que el usuario solo puede seleccionar el texto del primer edittext, lo cual es un problema para una app de notas. Otro problema es que el tamaño de fuente de letra del edittext solo se puede cambiar una vez, cosa que no quiero por funcionalidad de mi app.

**Chunks:** utilizé chuncked cada 1000 caracteres y en inicio parecia buena idea, utilizé el evento de escucha del scroll para agregar el texto por debajo del edittext utilizando append, pero esto hacia 2 cosa, me devolvia el focus al inicio del edittext y al seleccionar todo el texto, se tardaba en cargar todos los chunks faltantes.

Comment: Haz intentado hacer "chunks" del texto; separar el texto en varias partes e irlo agregando?

Comment: Claramente un **EditText** no está pensado para contener tanto texto. Probaste está librería https://github.com/s6joui/BigEditText?

Comment: probe esas dos soluciones y siguen sin cumplir mis requisitos o producen fallos.